# implementing recursion (or something else) in repeating program

Tags: python, recursion

I'm learning about recursion in Python, and I wrote a small program that I'd like to improve on for the sake of erudition.

The program repeatedly prints lines of asterisks which change colors. The program runs until I stop it. Right now it works as expected, but just by looking at it I can tell there must be a better way to write this recursively, or perhaps using another method.

Please post some answers that demonstrate how to improve this program. You don't have to make use of the `termcolor` module if you don't want to.

Below is my code:

```
import random
from termcolor import colored

s = random.choice('*******************',)
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white']
text_color = ""

def set_color(colors):
    global text_color
    text_color = random.choice(colors)

while True:
    for a in s:
        for b in s:
            for c in s:
                for d in s:
                    for e in s:
                        for f in s:
                            for g in s:
                                for h in s:
                                    for i in s:
                                        for j in s:
                                            for k in s:
                                                for l in s:
                                                    for m in s:
                                                        for n in s:
                                                            for o in s:
                                                                for p in s:
                                                                        print(colored(a, text_color)), (colored(b, text_color)), (colored(c, text_color)), (colored(d, text_color)), (colored(e, text_color)), (colored(f, text_color)), (colored(g, text_color)), (colored(h, text_color)), (colored(i, text_color)), (colored(j, text_color)), (colored(k, text_color)), (colored(l, text_color)), (colored(m, text_color)), (colored(n, text_color)), (colored(o, text_color)), (colored(p, text_color)), (colored(a, text_color)), (colored(b, text_color)), (colored(c, text_color)), (colored(d, text_color)), (colored(e, text_color)), (colored(f, text_color)), (colored(g, text_color)), (colored(h, text_color)), (colored(i, text_color)), (colored(j, text_color)), (colored(k, text_color)), (colored(l, text_color)), (colored(m, text_color)), (colored(n, text_color)), (colored(o, text_color)), (colored(p, text_color)); set_color(colors)
```

Comment: Stairway to Truth.... This is better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: Take your suggestions to the answer box!

Comment: What is `random.choice('*******************',)` supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `random.choice('*******************',)` will choose a random character from the string. Since all characters are '*' you can essentially replace the whole expression by `s = '*'`.

The nested loops are on the form `for x in s`. Since `s = '*'`, this is equivalent to `for x in '*'`. For a one-letter string, this is a loop with only one iteration - so it can be replaced with `x = 's'`.

The third thing to notice now is that all the variables named `a` through `p` are equal and contain an asterisk. They can all be removed, and instead use `s` wherever they are used.

Finally, the huge `print` statement is then full of `colored(s, text_color)`. They can be replaced by `' '.join(colored(s, text_color) for _ in range(32))`

So you end up with the following program:

```
import random
from termcolor import colored

s = '*'
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'magenta', 'cyan', 'white']
text_color = ''

def set_color(colors):
    global text_color
    text_color = random.choice(colors)

text_color = set_color(colors)
while True:
    print(' '.join(colored(s, text_color) for _ in range(32)))
    set_color(colors)
```

It can be further simplified:

```
import random
from termcolor import colored, COLORS
while True:
    color = random.choice(COLORS.keys())
    print(' '.join(colored('*', color) for _ in range(32)))
```

This is even more fun, it will use both background and foreground colors, and not use any spaces:

```
import os
from random import choice
from termcolor import colored, COLORS, HIGHLIGHTS
r, c = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
WIDTH=int(r+c) # actual terminal width under Linux
while True:
    print ''.join(colored('▄', choice(COLORS.keys()), choice(HIGHLIGHTS.keys())) for _ in range(WIDTH)),
```

Output:
[image: random colors everywhere!]

Comment: Excellent, this is really insightful.

Comment: Nice, you got the terminal size :)